# GKE Nginx Ingress - Assigning static ip

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have an ingress controller in a GKE cluster with `ingress.class`:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
```

I wish to assign a static ip to this ingress controller. I followed this tutorial for creating and assigning the static ip:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip

Basically I reserved a static IP and tried to assign it to the ingress using:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "my-ingress-static-ip"
```

**The Problem**

The ip address ingress did not changed to the new assigned static ip.

How should I assign this static IP to the ingress?

**My Configuration**

Controller deployed using:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.40.2/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

My Ingress yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-ingress
  namespace: development
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    # Disallow http - Allowed only with gce controller
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    # Enable client certificate authentication
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
    # Create the secret containing the trusted ca certificates
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: "development/api-ingress-ca-secret"
    # Specify the verification depth in the client certificates chain
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "1"
    # Automatically redirect http to https
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    # Use regex in paths
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    # For notifications we add the proxy headers
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |  
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    # Set a static ip for the ingress
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "my-ingress-static-ip"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - my-host.com
      secretName: api-tls-certificate
  rules:
  - host: my-host.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(v[0-9]/.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 443
```

Deleting the ingress or the controller did not fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That tutorial is only for the GCE ingress controller.

> Note: This tutorial does not apply to the NGINX Ingress Controller.

To set the IP address, you need to specify the actual ip address in the `spec:` [section](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/fb6a03ffb42cfbf682c3c7f400f46fb4802caa1c/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml#L286) of the LoadBalancer service.

```
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  loadBalancerIP: ACTUAL.IP.ADRESS.HERE
  ports:
```

As a note, make sure that your ip address is a regional static IP and not a global IP. This took me quite a while to figure out.

Comment: Thank you, this works well. Patch an existing nginx controller service using `kubectl patch svc ingress-nginx-controller -p '{"spec": {"loadBalancerIP": "MY_STATIC_IP"}}'`

Comment: In fact, the following, from https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/ makes things easy, so I can do `helm upgrade --install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx  --namespace "$${K8S_NAMESPACE}"  --set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP=192.0.2.13`

Comment: I think here the "That tutorial is only for the GCE ingress controller." is confusing, this is in fact for kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx", not for class "gce"

Comment: From the tutorial linked above https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip "Note: This tutorial uses the built-in GKE Ingress Controller and does not apply to the NGINX Ingress Controller."